# UIAlertView is not positioned at the center of the screen

Tags: ios, uialertview, xib

I have to fix some bugs in an old application and got a really weird one. All alert views are shown in the top left corner for some reason. App doesn't use storyboards, main window is loaded from xib. What can cause this?

**UPDATE:** Code to initialize alert view is pretty standard. I'm calling it inside one of the controllers of UITabBarController. Same bug occurs even if I leave app's main window empty and initialize alert view in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
UIAlertView *testAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                                    message:@"Message"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

[testAlert show];
```

[image: Weird alert view]

Comment: if I do this I get this crash: Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and [_UIAlertShimPresentingViewController shouldAutorotate] is returning YES

Comment: Can you add the code that you use to initialize and present your alert view?

Comment: @davetw12 it's pretty standard. Added code to initial post

Comment: Have you tried to run this on an actual device?

Comment: Also make sure that you're presenting your alert view in viewDidAppear or after viewDidAppear has been called.

Comment: @davetw12: yes to both questions

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by simply replacing the [alert show] with the present [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];